# Java - Mapping dynamic JSON to DTO

Tags: java, spring-mvc, dto

I have problem to map a json data to DTO's with following payload

```
"wigData": {
        "wig": {
            "0": {
                "parentWig": "",
                "wigName": "testing wig 1",
                "wigStart": "01/08/2017",
                "wigFromx": "1",
                "wigToy": "123",
                "wigEnd": "31/08/2017",
                "wigAchievementType": "number"
            },
            "1": {
                "parentWig": "",
                "wigName": "testing wig 2",
                "wigStart": "01/08/2017",
                "wigFromx": "1",
                "wigToy": "123",
                "wigEnd": "31/08/2017",
                "wigAchievementType": "number"
            }
        }
    }
```

The DTO's failed to map the `wig`'s payload since it is serialize data from [jquery json serializable](https://github.com/marioizquierdo/jquery.serializeJSON)

I have created DTO for that payload like this,

```
class WigData {
    private Wigs wigs;
// setter getter
}

class Wigs {
    private List<Wig> index;
// setter getter
}

class Wig {
    private String parentWig;
    private String wigName;
    private Date wigStart;
    private Date wigFromx;
    private BigDecimal wigToy;
    private String wigAchievementType;
// setter getter
}
```

this is the output from this DTO

```
wigData: {
  wigs: null
}
```

but no luck, can anyone please help to fix this?

since it is not possible now to change the payload

Comment: What library are you using to deserialize json? Jackson? What error do you get? By the way you miss `wigEnd` field from `Wig` object

Comment: thanks! @amicoderozer , i have fix that miss. yes i'm using Jakson, i dont get any error, but the response not mapped the DTO's. Please check my updated answer sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Check more on JSON array.**

Try using below:

```
"wigData": {
    "wig": [{
            "parentWig": "",
            "wigName": "testing wig 1",
            "wigStart": "01/08/2017",
            "wigFromx": "1",
            "wigToy": "123",
            "wigEnd": "31/08/2017",
            "wigAchievementType": "number"
        }, {
            "parentWig": "",
            "wigName": "testing wig 2",
            "wigStart": "01/08/2017",
            "wigFromx": "1",
            "wigToy": "123",
            "wigEnd": "31/08/2017",
            "wigAchievementType": "number"
        }
    ]
}

class WigData {
    private List<Wig> wig;
    // setter getter
}

class Wig {
    private String parentWig;
    private String wigName;
    private Date wigStart;
    private Date wigFromx;
    private BigDecimal wigToy;
    private String wigAchievementType;
// setter getter
}
```

Comment: well, thats not possible in my context sir, i'm using Json Serialize library which mapped the payload like inside my question. any hints sir?

Comment: i will check jquery json serialization and put another answer. But at backend side mapping works as i posted. I will look into the jquery json serialization  and get back to you in couple of hours.

Comment: use var json = $('#my-profile').serializeJSON({useIntKeysAsArrayIndex: true});

Comment: use {useIntKeysAsArrayIndex: true} while serializing json. and then use solution i provided it should work as it will convert array as i given in answer.

Comment: the solution is given on this page: https://github.com/marioizquierdo/jquery.serializeJSON/issues/69